# Xamarin Forms Push Notification with Firebase

Tags: firebase, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.forms

I tried to implement push notification for xamarin forms. First, I need to complete the android solution. Hi, I tried with one of plugin (https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification) but with this nuget plugin, notification is received only if the app is open (not receiving if app is closed). I think it is an issue in this plugin and people have reported, do you know any other plugin that can make solution for xamrin forms push notification with firebase?

Comment: If you use Android check if service, that get push notifications, is restarted after you close your app. Notice stop debugging mode will terminate the application and the service, service will not restart automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Android passes the notification information on app create, so you have to process it by your self:
So in your

MainActivity.cs->OnCreate

method you have to read the message like

```
if (Intent.Extras != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var myCustomMessage = Intent.Extras.GetString("MyMessage");
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
```

that "MyMessage" string in the Intent.Extras is the string that i put it in my notification string, I'm using PushSharp library to send custom notifications. You can find information how to use it on on web. But as i said, you have to process Intent.Extras on application startup by yourself; hope this helps u :)

Comment: is it possible to use pushSharp in xamarin.form project ?

Comment: hmm, i think no; it says "server side library". I used it on a server side .net 4.5 webApi project. So i'm calling a rest api to send notification to my clients via it :) Clients (ios-android) are just receivers (of course they can send notifications with calling that rest services too).

Answer (score 0):

I recently used firebase with mine, follow the instructions on this link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89731/how-to-implement-fcm-in-xamarin-forms. Also, to receive notifications when app is closed you would need to store the registrationId on the app's local storage and the xamarin Settings plugin easily does this for you. Hope this helps